# SHA1 not producing same hash value for same string input?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, hash, sha

I am busy with a login JFrame where the system will request the user to enter a username and password. The passwords are hashed using SHA-1 and stored in MySQL

The problem I am having is that the output is not consistently the same for the exact same password string.
I need to have a hash using SHA1 that will produce the same output so that I can verify it against the hash in the database, to prove that the user has entered the correct password.

Here is my coding for the sha1.

```
try
        {
            String password = txtPassword.getPassword().toString();

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(password.getBytes());

            byte byteData[] = md.digest();

            //convert the byte to hex format
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
             sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

            System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
```

Is there a problem with the coding above that will cause it to produce different outputs for the same string.

Comment: `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");`?

Comment: `"MD5"` does not sound like it would give you SHA-1...

Comment: Thanks, correct made. Sorry I was trying many different hashing algorithms.

Comment: @John I tried your code in ideone and it seems working fine. Are you sure the input is the same? (probably try to print out the password I guess)

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying different coding and I have found that the problem was with the obtaining the password from  the JPasswordField.

The solution I came to which produced the same hash for the password was one line that I had to edit from  `String password = txtPassword.getPassword().toString();`  to this  `String password = String.valueOf(txtPassword.getText());`

I realized that the problem was with reading it as a string not as a value.

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 0):

```
String password = txtPassword.getPassword().toString();
```

What is the code for this? This is most likely where the issue is, since setting password = "test" will give you the same results repeatedly.

Edit :

Try this :    String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for that line is for obtaining the password entered by the user. The password will be called from the JPasswordField and store it in the variable password. The system will need to create a hash value for this password and if the hash matches the hash in MySQL then user will be authenticated.

Comment: You don't want to be making it a string then, it's the reason getPassword returns char[] and not a string. To handle passwords you want to use the chars and then zero the array. [Note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText--)